# Only allow one job on a machine

Tags: jenkins

The way we're using Jenkins requires us to have two nodes defined for each machine.  One Jenkins node runs as a normal user (called Normal), and the other runs as the administrator (called Admin).  So they show up as two separate nodes, even though they exist on the same slave machine.

But, we're running into a concurrency problem. Because our job switches between the two nodes, there is a possibility of another job (Job B) being assigned to (for example) the Normal node, while the Admin node is working on its part of (e.g.) Job A.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins that if either the Normal node or the Admin node of a machine is being used, then it should NOT give the other node some other job?

To elaborate on this question--we have a test suite that we currently run serially.  All of our Jenkins masters have multiple slaves, so naturally we would like to take advantage of parallelization, so the suite doesn't spent 2 hours using one machine while the other ones sit idle.  So it's not really a matter of ensuring only one job runs at once, it really is a matter of telling Jenkins not to use a node when its partner node is busy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to two nodes on the same machine or one privileged or not; it's a matter of blocking one job from running while the other is still running.

I trust you are using [labels](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node) to [restrict what jobs can run on what nodes](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Labels+for+Resource+Assignment+and+Job+Queuing+in+Jenkins)

You can use [Build Blocker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/) to block the job from running while others are . There are [other plugin options](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?query=block) which may work for you as well.

You can also use the [Paramterized Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) to in-line the execution of the other job. It can be run as a build step or a post-build step.

You can also restrict the number of executors on a given node via `${JENKINS_URL}/computer/myNode/configure` | # of executors, so you don't run multiple jobs one the same node if that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I solved this problem:

1. Set the number of executors on each slave node to 1.
2. Force my job to take an executor for the whole length of the job.

Specifically, in the groovy script that we use for all our jobs, at the very top, after we find which two (admin and normal, running on the same slave) nodes we need, we use the following:
n

```
node(myNormalNode)
{
    //all the rest of the job, including:
    node(myAdminNode)
    {
        //other commands for the admin node
    } 
    //back to commands for the normal node
    node('master')
    {
        //code to run on master
     }
     //and so forth
}
```

This makes Jenkins not assign any other jobs to this computer until the first job is done.